# mPDF invoice print multiple invoices in one page

Tags: php, pdf, printing, cakephp-3.0, mpdf

So. I'm using mpdf 6.0 and my plan is to generate an invoice por every sale that is half page original for the client and the other half page as a copy for me.
But I can't seem to get the page division right. So I thought about using a custom page size. A5 in landscape mode. But when I need to print them they each take a full page. Is there any way to force 2 pdf pages per physical page. Or do I have to just treat the whole thing as one A4 page and just draw both invoices in the same page?

I'll try to improve the wording as soon as possible but right now I'm in a hurry.

Comment: What's the difference between the original and the copy? Can you just copy the file after creating it?

Comment: @Terminus I'm required by company policy to print both. One has an "original" watermark and the other has a "copy" watermark

Comment: Oh. Can you have 2 mpdf objects at the same time, adding all the same elements to both and then adding the appropriate watermark to the appropriate object?

Comment: @Terminus I'll try that. Good suggestion for some reason I was stuck with only using one object. Never even thought about multiple ones.

Comment: When you're banging your head against the wall, you lose some peripheral vision;) good luck